# @JoinColumnsOrFormulas cause n+1 issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am facing the n+1 query issue when I use @JoinColumnsOrFormulas or @JoinColumns with @NamedEntityGraph(includeAllAttributes = true)

I tried to also left join the entity in Specification and it also cause n+1 query issue.

Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "all", includeAllAttributes = true)
public class BookEntity implements JpaEntity {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CustomerEntity.class)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "customer", referencedColumnName = "number", insertable = false, updatable = false)),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "sub_customer", referencedColumnName = "sub_number", insertable = false, updatable = false)),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "'2019'", referencedColumnName = "year"))
    })
    private CustomerEntity customerEntity;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "customer")
public class CustomerEntity implements JpaEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "number", columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    private Integer number;
    @Column(name = "sub_number", columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    private Integer subNumber;
    @Column(name = "year")
    private String year;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Override
    @EntityGraph(value = "all")
    Page<BookEntity> findAll(Specification<BookEntity> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

I see that the query is correct. I see the join for the first query, so it looks like I have the full entity and no need to make n+1 query. But after correct query I see additional selects for the CustomerEntity.

Can someone help me to avoid n+1 issue with this case?

Comment: We also need CustomerEntity source to fuly understand. do you have eager or *toOne relation in this class?

Comment: @pdem CustomerEntity doesn't have a relation with BookEntity.  It's unidirectional relation